# Nautilus ignores noauto in fstab

Tags: 11.10, nautilus, fstab, automount

To prevent my mobile beeing mounted as storage , i put the following line in `/etc/fstab`:

```
/dev/disk/by-uuid/36DF-0070 /media/diamond vfat  noauto,nouser,defaults  0 0
```

Nautilus seems to ignore this and tries to mount the device, which is only prevented by using the `nousers` option (a windows appears, the device can only be mounted by root).

It seems to be a [known bug](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/udisks/+bug/865026) but the mentioned workaround doesn't work for me.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2):

You have misunderstood how `noauto` works.

From `fstab` man page:

> ```
>  noauto: do not mount when "mount -a" is given (e.g., at boot time)
> ```

It means that the partition would not be mounted at boot time, and is not even taken into consideration when you insert the device containing the partition after the boot.

In older versions of Nautilus, there was an option to set in `gconf-editor` to not automount inserted devices. Now it is in `dconf-editor`, in

```
org.gnome.desktop.media-handling/automount
```

(thanks to @lgarzo for the information).

Comment: It is now `org.gnome.desktop.media-handling/automount` in dconf-editor.

Comment: I found the option in dcon-editor:

Comment: Thanx , it worx!